# QEMU/KVM, using full physical disk is faster than raw .img file?

Tags: linux, virtualization, qemu, linux-kvm, virt-manager

When adding an HDD to a guest in QEMU/KVM in Virt-Manager, there are "qcow2" and "raw". "raw" seems to be storing the data in a file with the ".img" extension. It seems that I can pass the entire physical disk to the guest like [this post](https://www.windowsphoneinfo.com/threads/using-physical-disk-in-kvm-qemu-windows-vm.555232/) says, but is using the whole physical disk like that any faster than using the raw ".img" file?

I am going to use a dedicated physical drive for a guest anyway, but I guess passing the whole raw disk to the guest may damage the file system metadata if I let the host access that disk at the same time by a mistake. If I use a raw ".img" file on that drive, than it will be safe from such accident. But if the former is significantly faster, then it may be worth the risk.

```
<disk>
        <disk type="block" device="disk">
        <driver name="qemu" type="raw"/>
        <source dev="/dev/sdg"/> <======= whatever the device is on your system -- lsblk will show devices
        <target dev="vda" bus="virtio"/> (for 2nd virtio device then replace vda by vdb etc )
        # <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x06" slot="0x00" function="0x0"/> this line is generated when the VM is booted so you don't enter this one
</disk>
```

Answer (score 3):

Raw disk would faster, although it would make it difficult to move the
virtual machine to another computer (because requiring to clone the disk).

The reason Raw is faster is because for qcow2 (or any other virtual format)
any disk request would be passed among two file systems:

1. The request issued in the virtual machine will be handled by the
   driver in the VM, including all the administration involved with
   allocation of virtual sectors etc. which is actually only within
   the `.img` file, so within a fictional file-system.
2. The virtual driver then issues the request to the real physical
   disk, to another file-system, which would then do the same work of
   the allocation of physical sectors etc.

For the Raw disk, there is only one file-system - the virtual and
physical are then identical. However, in most cases the performance
improvement is only marginal and does not justify the inconvenience,